# How to escape page_title in a view when defined in the application helper? Error (nil) emitted from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Working in an app where a page_title method was defined in application_helper.rb as such:

```
  def page_title(title = nil)
    if title.present?
      content_for(:page_title) { "#{title} - SomeDomain.tld" }
    else
      content_for?(:page_title) ? content_for(:page_title) : "SomeDomain.tld"
    end
  end
```

In a view I need to pass this page_title on into some various links, example:

```
= link_to "http://www.some_bookmark_site.com/submit?url=#{URI::escape(request.url)}&title=#{URI::escape(page_title)}", :target =>"_blank"  do
```

However when I do this I am getting a nil error `"undefined method 'each_byte' for nil:NilClass"` which indicates obviously the method's returning a nil...

or is it that I need to pass a var in here instead?  Would appreciate clarification on how to form this all properly for such conditions.

Full trace: http://pastebin.com/gegDETUp

Just wanted to note that I'm still looking for an answer on this question.

Comment: Make sure you're doing `URI.escape`... I see a typo. The whole stack trace would be helpful, too.

Comment: yes, sorry, that was a typo as I'd changed it back over from a nokogiri method I was using that yielded the same result.  Added full trace for you as well.

Comment: @rkb so any new thoughts or updates after updating that as per your request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when i understand your question correctly, you are asking why your `page_title` method returns `nil`?

if that's the case, you should have a look at how to use `content_for` and `yield` within templates:

```
# in the helper
content_for(:page_title, 'title') # => nil

# in the view
yield :page_title # => here goes the 'title'
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield

Comment: Was able to use something like this to make it a bit more sane: http://zetetic.net/blog/2010/05/18/pretty-page-title-in-rails-3/